# Почему не проходит метод POST

Tags: reactjs, http, fetch

Почему не проходит метод пост?
Есть такой код

```
import decode from 'jwt-decode';
export default class AuthService {
    constructor(domain) {
        this.domain = 'http://id.cryptofiles.org:2212/api/users/login/'
        this.fetch = this.fetch.bind(this)
        this.login = this.login.bind(this)
        this.getProfile = this.getProfile.bind(this)
    }

    login(username, password) {
        // Get a token
        const url = 'http://id.cryptofiles.org:2212/api/users/login/';
        const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        return this.fetch(proxyurl + url, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode:'cors',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",

              },
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                password,
            })
        }).then(res => {

            this.setToken(res.auth_token)
            return Promise.resolve(res);
        })
    }

    loggedIn() {
        // Checks if there is a saved token and it's still valid
        const token = this.getToken()

        return !!token && !this.isTokenExpired(token) // handwaiving here
    }

    isTokenExpired(token) {
        try {
            const decoded = decode(token);

            if (decoded.exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (err) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    setToken(idToken) {
        // Saves user token to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', idToken)

    }

    getToken() {
        // Retrieves the user token from localStorage
        return localStorage.getItem('id_token')
    }

    logout() {
        // Clear user token and profile data from localStorage
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    }

    getProfile() {
        // Using jwt-decode npm package to decode the token
        return (this.getToken());
    }


    fetch(url, options) {
        // performs api calls sending the required authentication headers
        const headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",

        }

        if (this.loggedIn()) {
            headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.getToken()
        }

        return fetch(url, {
            headers,
            ...options
        })
            .then(this._checkStatus)
            .then(response => response.json())
    }

    _checkStatus(response) {
        // raises an error in case response status is not a success
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            return response
        } else {
            var error = new Error(response.statusText)
            error.response = response
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код авторизирует пользователя и сохраняет токен.Но когда я смотрю на панель разработчика, проходит только один запрос login с таким телом :

```
Request URL: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://id.cryptofiles.org:2212/api/users/login/
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 34.225.198.210:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: access-control-allow-origin,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-headers
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 18 May 2018 08:29:20 GMT
Server: Cowboy
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 vegur
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/login
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
```

только options приходят, а сам токен через post нет.Может подскажете в чем ошибка?
Заранее всем спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0):

В этом месте:

```
    return fetch(url, {
        headers,
        ...options
    })
```

у тебя `headers` перезаписываются. И передаются только headers из `options`.

Нужно мерджить headers

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить токен в заголовки в options вместо дополнительной переменной для них:

```
if (this.loggedIn()) {
    options.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.getToken()
}
return fetch(url, options)...
```

Ну или как-то объединить заголовки. Например, так:

```
fetch(url, {
     ...options, 
     headers: Object.assign({}, options.headers, headers)
})
```